# Ansible/Jinja2 nested escaping

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

Is there any way to have nested escaping of jinja2 template?

```
  replace:
    path: /etc/my_file
    regexp: '^my_var = ""'
    replace: !unsafe "my_var = {{getv '/{{ variable}}/my_dir/my_file'}}"
```

I'd like to replace `my_var = ""` with `my_var = {{getv '/staging/my_dir/my_file'}}`

In this case, {{getv}} shouldn't be templated (external parenthesis), but {{variable}} inside (internal parenthesis) should be.

Comment: "Whenever you have problems with conflicting characters in Ansible, a rule of thumb is to output them as a string in a Jinja expression." see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32283447/2553262

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to concatenate the *replace* string. For example

```
  vars:
    lbrackets: "{{ '{{' }}"
    rbrackets: "{{ '}}' }}"
    quote: "'"

  tasks:
    - replace:
        path: /etc/my_file
        regexp: '^my_var = ""(.*)$'
        replace: "{{ 'my_var = ' ~
                     lbrackets ~ 'getv ' ~ quote ~
                     '/staging/my_dir/my_file' ~ quote ~ rbrackets
                     }}"
```