# How do I optimize performance of Ansible playbook with regards to SSH connections?

Tags: performance, time, ssh, ansible, performance-testing

I have the below playbook `test1.yml` that gets `istat` data for 26 subfolders under this directory `/var/myfile/pdf`.

```yaml
  tasks:

    - name: List directories
      raw: "ls -d "/var/myfile/pdf/*/"
      register: subdir

    - name: List pid files
      raw: "istat {{ item }}"
      with_items: "{{ subdir.stdout_lines }}"
```

I run the playbook and it takes 29 seconds to complete.

```bash
time ANSIBLE_SSH_PIPELINING=True ansible-playbook -i=10.9.9.12, -f 30 test1.yml -vvv
```

After the playbook completes below is the time taken details output:

```bash
Output:

    real    0m29.144s
    user    0m6.206s
    sys     0m5.618s
```

I now put the same code with `istat` task in `include_tasks` file like below.

Playbook `test2.yml`

```yaml
  tasks:

    - name: List directories
      raw: "ls -d "/var/myfile/pdf/*/"
      register: subdir

    - name: List pid files
      include_tasks: "innertest.yml"
      with_items: "{{ subdir.stdout_lines }}"
```

```bash
cat innertest.yml
```

```yaml
      - raw: "istat {{ item }}"
```

```bash
time ANSIBLE_SSH_PIPELINING=True ansible-playbook -i=10.9.9.12, -f 30 test2.yml -vvv

Output:

    real    0m59.044s
    user    0m18.203s
    sys     0m10.118s
```

As you can see the time with the same amount of task has more than doubled due to `include_tasks`

In the debug, I also see there are 26 SHH connections triggered for the 26 sub-directories `with_items` for the same target host `10.9.9.12`.

I'm not sure of how this works internally but it would have been nice to have a single SSH connection for `istat` for 26 sub-directories on the same host for performance reasons.

Is there a way to increase the performance for `include_tasks` and bringing down the number of ssh connections to the same host ?

Answer (score 0):

> *Is there a way to increase the performance ... and bringing down the number of SSH connections to the same host?*

I understand that you like to know "How to increase the performance and decrease execution time of specific tasks?".

To achieve your goal you may have a look into the following example, documentation and further links.

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Gather subdirectories
    shell:
      cmd: "ls -d /home/{{ ansible_user }}/*/"
      warn: false
    register: subdirs

  - name: Gather stats (loop)
    shell:
      cmd: "stat {{ item }}"
      warn: false
    loop: "{{ subdirs.stdout_lines }}"
    loop_control:
      label: "{{ item }}"

  - name: Gather stats (list)
    shell:
      cmd: "stat {% raw %}{{% endraw %}{{ subdirs.stdout_lines | join(',') }}{% raw %}}{% endraw %}"
      warn: false
    register: result

  - name: Show result
    debug:
      var: result.stdout
```

resulting into execution and runtimes of

```
TASK [Gather subdirectories] ***********************
changed: [test.example.com]
Sunday 31 July 2022 (0:00:01.412) 0:00:01.448 ******

TASK [Gather stats (loop)] *************************
changed: [test.example.com] => (item=/home/user/01/)
changed: [test.example.com] => (item=/home/user/02/)
changed: [test.example.com] => (item=/home/user/03/)
...
changed: [test.example.com] => (item=/home/user/24/)
changed: [test.example.com] => (item=/home/user/25/)
changed: [test.example.com] => (item=/home/user/26/)
Sunday 31 July 2022 (0:00:31.715) 0:00:33.164 ******

TASK [Gather stats (list)] *************************
changed: [test.example.com]
Sunday 31 July 2022 (0:00:01.361) 0:00:34.525 ******

Gather subdirectories ------------------------ 1.41s
Gather stats (loop) ------------------------- 31.72s
Gather stats (list) -------------------------- 1.36s
Show result ---------------------------------- 0.08s
```

I've also tested with the [`raw` module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57805603/6771046) instead of using the `shell` module

```
Gather stats (loop) via 'raw' ---------------- 4.96s
Gather stats (list) via 'raw' ---------------- 0.27s
```

Whereby looping over commands and providing one parameter for the command per run results into a lot of overhead and multiple SSH connections as well, providing the list directly to the command might be possible and increase performance and decrease runtime and resource consumption.

> *it would have been nice to have a single SSH connection for `istat` for 26 sub-directories on the same host for performance reasons.*

For this you would simply need to execute your task just once, resulting into one SSH connection only. To do so, you might be able provide a list of directories to the command directly via Ansible, like in example

```bash
istat {01,02,03,...,24,25,26}
```

As you can see, for this the command needs to include curly braces which needs to be escaped in Ansible. The directory list would need to be a string, whereby the directories are comma separated. For this you can use the `join()` filter.

Finally you would end up with

```yaml
istat {% raw %}{{% endraw %}{{ subdir.stdout_lines | join(',') }}{% raw %}}{% endraw %}"
```

**Similar Question with Answer**

- [Ansible - 'with_items' pointed directly at 'vars' rather than expanding them first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73166997/6771046)
- [Ansible Issue #76380 - "*Improve Ansible performance*"](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/76380)

---

**Further Documentation**

- [Escaping (double) curly braces in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32279729/6771046)
- [Template Designer Documentation - Escaping](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#escaping)
- [Manipulating strings](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#manipulating-strings)
- [How to join a list of strings in Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47247544/6771046)
- [Brace Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html), if you are on `AIX` you have a look into [Shell Parameter expansion not working in AIX](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/640991/)