# How to seepd up Ansible copy task running in a loop?

Tags: performance, loops, shell, time, ansible

Below is my playbook that searches for all `*.txt` files and takes a copy of each using the copy task.

```yaml
---
- name: Backup txt files
  hosts: remotehost
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: List txt files in /opt/cusfiles/
      find:
        paths: /opt/cusfiles/
        patterns: '*.txt'
      register: txt_files

    - name: Backup txt files
      copy:
        src: "{{ item.path }}"
        dest: "{{ item.path }}.bkp"
      with_items: "{{ txt_files.files }}"
```

The playbook runs on Ansible Tower and the results are shared in a playbook run.

The issue is when the number of files exceeds 500+, this task takes more than 25 minutes.

I was able to cut down on time to make copies by using `raw` module instead of `copy module`

```yaml
raw: "cp {{ item.path }} {{ item.path }}.bkp"
```

This task however still takes 15-20 minutes.

Can I improve the time to complete the run using Ansible or UNIX skills?

Comment: Does [How do I optimize performance of Ansible playbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73181784/6771046) or [Ansible: How to optimize running speed of a playbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74764504/6771046) answer your question?

Comment: @U880D in the reference you provided you seem to be constructing `stat` command for a single run for the looping files. I'm not sure how can we do the same for `copy` command. Could we loop and construct a variable having  all the files copy command and then simply run that single command one time than in a loop ?

Comment: That's written in the answers, links and documentation provided. You need just to understand the approach, adopt it and adjust it for your needs. The time for your reply was that short that I wonder how you were able to read all that?

Comment: i will go for something like this unless you / community suggests something better -> `for file in hello.txt yellow.txt bellow.txt; do cp $file ${file}.bkp; done` with `raw` module i.e `"for file in {{ allfiles }}; do cp $file ${file}.bkp; done"`

Comment: @Ashar That may be a little faster, but the may problem remains the same: calling `cp` for each file individually takes time; so, why not create a backup dir and copy all the files in it with something like `cp {{ allfiles }} ./backup/`?

Comment: @Fravadona Thank you, thats right and the solution to implement

Answer (score -1):

You could delegate the task to a python script. With a python script (or any other language for that matter that supports concurrency) you can perform complex tasks efficiently.

From your playbook, it would look like this:

```
- name: Run Python script with Ansible
  hosts: your_target_servers
  tasks:
    - name: Execute Python script
      command: python /path/to/your/script.py
```

Your script would live in the files directory of your ansible project and would need a copy task that copies the script to the server.