# Is using an archive instead of individual files make ansible copy module faster?

Tags: ansible

I know that it is recommended to use the `synchronize` module for transferring large files. I am wondering if making a `.zip` archive of files and transferring them using the `copy` module makes it faster instead of copying let's say 20 files ? My reasoning is that `copy` module would have to check only one `zip` file for checksum and that would make it much faster. Is this true?

Comment: `synchronize` (rsync) sends only differences (increments). In any [IaC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrastructure_as_code) this should be preferred over `copy` both in terms of cost and speed.

Comment: Your assumption is correct for files which needs to be copied and written full, the first time or just once. See in example [Ansible: How to optimize running speed of a playbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74764504/6771046) or other background information [How do I optimize performance of Ansible playbook with regards to SSH connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73181784/6771046). Please take note about the other comment! The answer will depend on how often you need to copy them, if the files are changing and how much, etc. ... in other words, your complete Use Case.

Comment: @VladimirBotka Yeah, but does synchronize module ensure file integrity? The copy module does hashing comparison.

Comment: @rocky_alpine, use option `--checksum`. See [man rsync](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.1) (Next time, read the doc before asking).

Comment: If you read [ansible.posix.synchronize](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/synchronize_module.html) you'll see the option [checksum](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/synchronize_module.html#parameter-checksum).

Comment: I know that sychronize module have checksum. Copy module is not recommended for large file transfers because it does hashing etc. If you use hashing in synchronize module, that defeats the purpose (higher speed of transfer) of it.