# How to delete all subdirectories except a few?

Tags: ansible, subdirectory, delete-file

Using Ansible, I need to ensure, all of the subfolders of a certain directory do not exist *except* for a few, that must be retained.

The list to be kept will be specified externally -- say, as `subfolders_to_keep`.

The only way I can see is to first use the [`find`-module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html) to enumerate the subdirectories, and then, using [`file`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html), delete all, that aren't exceptional -- in a loop.

That would be a fairly long loop here — of the 50-plus entries, only 4 are to survive. Perhaps, there is a more elegant way?

Answer (score 1):

> ***That would be a fairly long loop here***

Right, with significant performance effects. See in example [Ansible: How to optimize running speed of a playbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74762326/6771046) or [How do I optimize performance of Ansible playbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73181784/6771046)

> ***There is a more elegant way?***

Since there is no out-of-box module available for such kind of tasks, in your specific Use Case

- Using [`shell` module – Execute shell commands on targets](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html) with `find` or `rm` together with excludes. See in example

  - [How to delete all files in a directory except some?](https://superuser.com/questions/529854/)
  - [Delete files and exclude some with `find`](https://superuser.com/questions/679205/)
- Writing a short script and using the [`script` module – Runs a local script on a remote node after transferring it](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/script_module.html). Maybe read before about [How to execute a `shell` script on a Remote Server using Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73363872/6771046).
- [Developing an own Custom Module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_modules_general.html). An example in Pyhton can be found under [Custom Module `library/pygrep.py`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75250253/6771046). Shell or Bash is also possible but probably more complex. An example can be found under [Example Module `between.sh`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74614509/6771046).